# react-native - Why do I have to refresh to see the result of update image

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, mobile, rendering

I'm still a beginner in react. For now, I'm learning about react-native, I tried to upload a photo, but the screen only shows me `undefined` value on each data from redux.

Is there something wrong with `useEffect`? I think it's all about `useEffect`, I hope someone can help me. Here's the code:

```
import { getUserById, updateImageUser } from '../../stores/actions/user';
import { launchCamera, launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';

const editProfile = props =>{
 const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        {
          title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
          message:
            'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
            'so you can take awesome pictures.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('You can use the camera');
        const result = await launchCamera({
          selectionLimit: 1,
        });

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', {
          name: result.assets[0].fileName,
          type: result.assets[0].type,
          uri: result.assets[0].uri,
        });
        const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
        const data = await dispatch(updateImageUser(userId, formData));
        // console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err.response);
    }
  };

return (
  <View style={styles.containerPhoto}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => requestCameraPermission()}
      style={styles.rounded}>
      {user.data?.image ? (
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri: `https://res.cloudinary.com/atma-jaya-yogyakarta/image/upload/v1669068823/${user.data.image}`,
          }}
          style={{resizeMode: 'cover', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
          borderRadius={50}
        />
      ) : (
        <Image source={require('../../assets/Avatar.png')} />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={styles.name}>
      {user.data.name ? user.data.name : 'empty'}
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.role}>
      {user.data.profession ? user.data.profession : 'empty'},{' '}
      {!user.data.nationality ? 'empty' : user.data.nationality}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

The value is success, but the screen still didn't change. I have to refresh it manually. Please help, it has already taken me hours.

Thank you, everybody!

Comment: Not sure if this works, but have you tried using the `Image` component instead of `ImageBackground`?

Comment: still not work mate :(

Comment: Where does the `user.data` come from? I don't see it on the code example

Comment: sorry louis, i forgot to add it. here's user data come from  const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
 that is from selector redux

Comment: i already edit about the user data

Comment: This might be a weird suggestion, but try adding the key prop to each image component. For example on the `ImageBackground`  add
```key={`image-${user.data?.image}`}```  and on the `Image` add `key="placeholder-image"`

Comment: @LuísMestre still not work luis. is my useffect already correct?

Comment: SOLVED! thank you everyone to respond

Comment: if you found the solution please give an answer to the question 

Answer (score 0):

so in my case, i have redux action called getUserById(userId). so i just call it again below this code   const data = await dispatch(updateImageUser(userId, formData)). so the function will re-fetch the data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).